# AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'refs'

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I am trying to write a python program that show me the stock price chart for google.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

#set the start and end date
start_date = "2020-03-01" 
end_date = "2020-04-12"

#choose stock ticker symbol
ticker = "GOOGLE" 

#get stock price
stock = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date) 
print(stock)

#obtain dates
stock["Date"]=stock.index.map(mdates.date2num) 

#choose figure size
fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10, 6)) 

#format date to place on the x-axis
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y') 
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

# Plot data.
plt.plot(stock['Date'], stock['Adj Close'], c='red')
 
# Format plot.
plt.title("The Stock Price", fontsize=16) 
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=10)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel("Price", fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

But the program keeps showing me this error.

```
AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'refs'
```

the error keeps focusing on this exception 'Date' somehow during handle it another exception occurred.

Update on the problem: somehow solved itself I don't know how but I run the same code again after 24 h and it gave me the desired output.

Comment: Please, edit your question to include full traceback you get. Check [ask].

Comment: @buran Thank you for your advice, I tried to do that, but the system refused to post my question because it has many codes. There is an update on the problem

Comment: Maybe try posting the traceback to a pastebin website or somewhere if its that long, and include it as a link